# tikz draw is giving me an error

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a state diagram, and although many similar ones worked with no issue, this specific one seems to give this error for no reason.

The error I get when compiling it with `pdflatex` is

```
! Package tikz Error: (, +, coordinate, pic, or node expected.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.21    \draw[input] (start) to \node
                               [above,sloped] {a} (a);
```

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}   % for diagrams
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    state/.style={circle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, node distance=1.5cm},
    start/.style={name=start},
    input/.style={->, thick, shorten >= 1mm, shorten <= 1mm},
]
    \node[state, start] {\(q_0\)};
    \node[state, above right=of start] (a) {\(q_1\)};
    \node[state, below right=of start] (b) {\(q_2\)};

    \draw[input] (start) to \node[above,sloped] {a} (a);
    \draw[input] (start) to \node[below,sloped] {b} (b);
    \draw[input, loop above] (start) to \node[above] {c} (start);
    \draw[input] (start.west)+(-1cm,0) to (start.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

An example of a similar diagram which does work is

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}   % for diagrams
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    state/.style={circle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, node distance=1.5cm},
    start/.style={name=start},
    input/.style={->, thick, shorten >= 1mm, shorten <= 1mm},
]
    \node[state, start] {\(q_0\)};
    \node[state, right=of start] (odd) {\(q_1\)};

    \draw[input, bend left=40] (start) to node[below] {a,b,c} (odd);
    \draw[input, bend left=40] (odd) to node[above] {a,b,c} (start);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `\draw[input] (start) to \node[above,sloped] {a} (a);` you should write `\draw[input] (start) to node[above,sloped] {a} (a);` . See difference how is inserted `node` .

Comment: @Zarko thank you so much!! I spent forever trying all sorts of stuff, didn't spot the typo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `\node` but `node` inside a path (see also [Zarko's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530715/tikz-draw-is-giving-me-an-error/530718#comment1342010_530715), which I see just now.)

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}   % for diagrams
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    state/.style={circle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, node distance=1.5cm},
    start/.style={name=start},
    input/.style={->, thick, shorten >= 1mm, shorten <= 1mm},
]
    \node[state, start] {\(q_0\)};
    \node[state, above right=of start] (a) {\(q_1\)};
    \node[state, below right=of start] (b) {\(q_2\)};

    \draw[input] (start) to node[above,sloped] {a} (a);
    \draw[input] (start) to node[below,sloped] {b} (b);
    \draw[input, loop above] (start) to node[above,midway] {c}  (start);
    \draw[input] (start.west)+(-1cm,0) to (start.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may use `quotes` here if you do not like the `node` syntax. (But if you add the babel package, please remember also to add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`.)

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}   % for diagrams
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    state/.style={circle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, node distance=1.5cm},
    start/.style={name=start},
    input/.style={->, thick, shorten >= 1mm, shorten <= 1mm},
]
    \node[state, start] {\(q_0\)};
    \node[state, above right=of start] (a) {\(q_1\)};
    \node[state, below right=of start] (b) {\(q_2\)};

    \draw[input] (start) to["a" sloped] (a);
    \draw[input] (start) to["b" sloped] (b);
    \draw[input, loop above] (start) to["c"]  (start);
    \draw[input] (start.west)+(-1cm,0) to (start.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks... I can't believe I didn't spot the typo... I looked over a million times and could not spot the difference

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon I think many who start using Ti*k*Z are tempted to add backslashes, which they are used from LaTeX. I did so, too. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Extend of my comment, as supplement to @Schrödinger's cat answer, based on `tikz` library `automata`:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}   % for diagrams
\usetikzlibrary{automata, 
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
           node distance = 11mm and 11mm,
            state/.style = {circle, draw=blue!60, very thick, fill=blue!5, 
                            minimum size=2em, inner sep=0pt},
               shorten > = 1mm, shorten < = 1mm, 
                           thick,
            initial text = , initial distance = 9mm,
every edge quotes/.style = {sloped}
]
\node (start) [state, initial] {\(q_0\)};
\node (a)     [state, above right=of start] {\(q_1\)};
\node (b)     [state, below right=of start] {\(q_2\)};
%
\path[->]   (start) edge["$a$"]   (a) 
            (start) edge["$b$"]   (b)
            (start) edge[loop above,looseness=10,"$c$"] (start);% default looseness=8
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]